# Laravel session sharing for main and subdomain

Tags: laravel, session, cross-site

I have 1 main domain and 2 subdomains like **example.com**, **abc.example.com** , **xyz.example.com**. These domains are pointing to same direcotry single projet.I want to share session between these 3 domains. I have scrolled through many articles and tried many solutions.

I found some solutions works for subdomains only. like setting **session domain** as **.example.com**. But its work fine for only subdomains not for main.

Guide me to the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by just adding the main domain as SESSION_DOMAIN in the .env file.